# 403 Forbidden error When calling webservice method from ASP.net Application

Tags: web-services

Need help urgetly,

I am trying to access a web service from a remote computer. I am able to browse  the web service link from the browser,  and able to communicate from windows application But when i try to call from asp.net application which is hosted on IIS 6 on windows server 2003  getting HTTP 403 and some times 501 not implemented errors.

Please help me out.

Thanks In Advance.

Hari.

Answer (score 1):

I have Found the solution for my problem here.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1860412.aspx/1?403+Forbidden+error+When+calling+webservice+method+from+ASP+net+Application

Thanks to Gaurav.